# New telegram windows open as I try to open tg channel via link

Tags: flatpak, telegram

When I try to open a tg-channel via link in browser (Firefox 98.0), it proceeds to dialog "Choose an app to open this link". Of course I choose TG, and then strange things happens: new, independent TG window opens (I had one already running), like a new client. How can I get rid off this issue? I have Telegram app installed via Flatpak. Tried to reinstall it, and it didn't help. Telegram version is the lates't, it is 3.6.

It's how the tray looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David, it's Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0):

First shutdown all instances of Telegram and then try:

```
sudo flatpak update
```

Start Telegram, and it should be fixed.